# How are native methods for JDK loaded?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

While reading JDK source code, I found that some methods are native, but there's no `System.loadLibrary` or `System.load` in their static block, so how are those methods actually loaded?

So I guess those methods are built-in in the JVM. Just wonder how are them loaded for specific class. Say, `StrictMath`. As follows:

```
public final StrictMath {
    public static native double cos(double a);
}
```

So I can find the source code for this native method, just wonder how is it loaded for this specific class.

Comment: In case of [Strict]Math, no library linkage is needed, as the JVM treats its methods as *instrinsic* operations, replacing them right in the interpreter and compiler when encountering an invocation of one of these methods. For other JRE classes, `loadLibrary` is not needed when the library is already loaded, which always applies to the JVM’s library hosting the core functions. You may notice the presence of `private static native void registerNatives(); static { registerNatives(); }` in such classes, which will trigger the linkage at initialization time.

Comment: @Holger In the interpreter `StrictMath` methods are not intrinsics, JVM still performs a regular native symbol lookup for them. But yes, the library with these symbols is already loaded.

Comment: @apangin but why do `java.lang.Object` et al have this `registerNatives()` call but `StrictMath` has not?

Comment: @Holger I *suppose* this is an optimization to avoid multiple dynamic lookups for each method. Native methods of `Object`, `Class`, `Thread` etc. are heavily used during VM startup (unlike `StrictMath`), so this small optimization helps to improve startup time a bit.

Answer (score 5):

The binding of all native methods is performed lazily on the first invocation, unless those methods were explicitly bound earlier by a call to JNI [RegisterNatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods) function.

So, on the first invocation of a native method JVM asks the dynamic linker to find a symbol named `Java_package_Class_method` in one of the loaded shared libraries. For instance, on Linux a call to [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) does the job.

As to `StrictMath` methods, there is no need to call `System.loadLibrary`, because the shared library with `StrictMath` symbols (`libjava.so` on Linux or `java.dll` on Windows) is already loaded. Actually, JVM loads `libjava.so` early at start up phase, because this library contains the native implementation of the core Java methods required for VM bootstrap.

Check what symbols `libjava.so` contains:

```
$ nm /usr/java/jdk-11.0.1/lib/libjava.so | grep Java_

....
00000000000146c0 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_acos
00000000000146b0 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_asin
00000000000146d0 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_atan
0000000000014710 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_atan2
0000000000014680 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_cos
0000000000014730 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_cosh
0000000000014770 T Java_java_lang_StrictMath_expm1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the responsibility of the `Bootstrap Classloader` (responsible for loading key java classes from `java.lang` package), which is written in native code.