# Call to System.loadLibrary() for FileOutputStream methods

Tags: java

I was checking out the source code for `FileOutputStream` class in Java and I noticed some native methods. To my understanding of native methods there should be a call to `System.loadLibrary()` somewhere, but I can not find it anywhere in the JDK source. I would like to find the dynamic library which contains the implementation of the native methods and also see the actual call to `System.loadLibrary()`. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

To rephrase my question, I would like to find out how JDK loads native code without `loadLibrary` and to actually see where is that configured in the repository.

Link to source: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54085467/how-are-native-methods-for-jdk-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. jdk7u repository is obsolete. It hasn't been updated for more than 8 years. The up-to-date repository is at https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file
2. The native implementation of `FileOutputStream` methods is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/158e145e3a42/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/FileOutputStream_md.c).
3. As the path suggests, this native code is a part of libjava (`libjava.so` or `java.dll`).
4. `libjava` is not the JVM, but it is still the essential part of Java Class Library, since it contains the native methods for basic classes like `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.ClassLoader` etc. That's why JVM preloads `libjava` during bootstrap, see [`ClassLoader::initialize`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/158e145e3a42/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classLoader.cpp#l1479).
5. As long as `libjava` is unconditionally preloaded by the JVM, there is no need to call `System.loadLibrary`.

Comment: I would like to see inside that repository some sort of reference to this file that triggers a load for that method. It must be configured somewhere, right?

Comment: @MichaelMunta You mean, [this code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/158e145e3a42/src/hotspot/share/runtime/os.cpp#l534)?

Comment: Yes, but additionally where does that java.dll come from? Is it not part of the repository?

Comment: @MichaelMunta It is in [java.base/share/native/libjava](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee1d592a9f53/src/java.base/share/native/libjava)

Comment: And where is FileOutputStream there?

Comment: @MichaelMunta [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee1d592a9f53/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/FileOutputStream_md.c)

Comment: And final question is, where does this repository create this dll as opposed to looking for it and loading it?

Comment: In [makefiles](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee1d592a9f53/make/modules/java.base)

Answer (score 0):

The implementations for the native methods in `FileOutputStream` are included in the JVM. `System.loadLibrary()` is used with external libraries that need to be loaded separately - it's not needed when the native methods are already compiled into the JVM.

You can see the source code by [searching the source code for mentions of "FileOutputStream" in C language](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/search?l=C&q=FileOutputStream).

The implementation is platform specific: for example, for Windows you'll find  [FileOutputStream_md.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/native/java/io/FileOutputStream_md.c) which calls functions in [io_util_md.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c).

Comment: What do you mean by already compiled into the JVM? How would I be able to avoid `System.loadLibrary()` in my own code?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to see in the repository where this C implementation is "loaded".

Comment: @MichaelMunta the JVM has native and non-native parts, the non-native part (that written in Java) like 'FileOutputStream' class uses calls to native part via methods with 'native' modifier. The 'System.loadLibrary()' call is for external libraries, that are not part of JVM. But to link external native library to Java object you also need to use 'native' modifier on Java method, so it probably confused you.

Comment: I understand, but there should be some makefile or something in the repository that makes a reference to this file, right?

Comment: @MichaelMunta JDK build process is very complicated, sure there are some make files, but they are *very* far from some small standalone app, as you could seen in examples. What exactly are you trying to find or solve ?

Comment: @AlexChernyshev well I am looking at this from an educational perspective. For example, I am trying to find which line would I need to remove from somewhere which would make that native method not know where its implementation was.